# How to set datetimepicker2 minDate value to datetimepicker1 date value?

Tags: vb.net

I have two datetimepicker.. Let's say it is datetimepicker1 and datetimepicker2. When I choose a date using datetimepicker1, datetimepicker2 mimimumdate will become the date of datetimepicker1. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what code have you got so far?

Comment: datetimepicker2.mindate = datetimepicker1.value.toString("d") and now its working thank you guys for answers.

Comment: @user3418036 did you check the answer I provided awhile ago?

Comment: Yhup .. thanks.. I get a clue on how to do it! Thans Man!!

Answer (score 0):

This will work just fine for you. I dragged two controls onto the form and did this on the `DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged Event`

```
  Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    DateTimePicker2.MinDate = DateTimePicker1.Value 'Set the min value
    DateTimePicker2.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value 'Set the date to second picker from the first one
  End Sub
```

I didn't handle the second `DateTime` control at all, not sure what you want to do with this...